# Javascript setTimeout and prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, settimeout

My task is very simple I need two workers running.

```
var taskNum = 0;

function Task() {
  var me = this;
  this.name = '#' + ++taskNum;

  Task.prototype.run = function () {
   console.log(me.name);
   setTimeout(me.run, 1000);
  }
}

var t1 = new Task();
t1.run();
var t2 = new Task();
t2.run();
```

The output should be 1,2,1,2 but it is:
    1
    2
    1
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2

This could be solved by changing 'Task.prototype.run' to 'this.run'.
But can this be fixed by not removing the prototype, because I need it in complex solution?

Answer (score 5):

That's because you override `Task.protoype.run` inside the construction function itself, and you set the new version to use the latest `me` variable.

A more common way to build a class is:

```js
var taskNum = 0;

function Task() {
  this.name = '#' + ++taskNum;
}

Task.prototype.run = function () {
  console.log(this.name);
  setTimeout(Task.prototype.run.bind(this), 1000);
}

var t1 = new Task();
t1.run();
var t2 = new Task();
t2.run();
```

Comment: don't forget to `bind` on `run`!

Comment: @DanielA.White - was editing while you commented :-)

Comment: Feel free to use setTimeout(this.run.bind(this), 1000)

Comment: @dangor - Thanks, I rather be explicit and uber-clear.

Comment: @Amit what is `bind` doing here?

Comment: @Manwal it causes the next execution of the function (the one coming from the setTimeout) to be called in the context of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript there is no variable scope like public,private etc . So the object of **me** gets overridden after executing second **new Task()** line
That's why you are getting that output

You can confirm this by creating two object first then calling run method

```
var t1 = new Task();
var t2 = new Task();
t1.run();
t2.run();
```

Now you will get output like  2 2 2 2 2 .....

To solve this issue you can pass tha Task object as parameter in run function like this:

```
t1.run(t1);
```

And then change your prototype run function as

```
Task.prototype.run = function (taskObject) {
    console.log(taskObject.name);
    setTimeout(taskObject.run, 1000);
}
```

Not tested but most likely it will work

Comment: That's not a good idea at all. The purpose of an object is to have properties that can be accessed in it's own context.